# Given special matrix, how to partition into linear independence and linear dependent set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, span

Suppose we are given a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Then form a matrix $M$

$M = \begin{bmatrix} A & BA & B^2A & \ldots & B^n  A \end{bmatrix}$

**How can you partition the columns this matrix into linearly dependent and independent sets?**

---

Attempt:

going from the left, suppose $B^{k+1}A$ is the first vector that is linearly dependent on the previous columns, then

$$B^{k+1}A = c_0 A + c_1 BA + \ldots + c_{k}B^kA$$

Then

$$BB^{k+1}A = B^{k+2}A = c_0 AB + c_1 B^2A + \ldots + c_{k}B^{k+1}A$$

But $$B^{k+1}A = A = c_0 A + c_1 BA + \ldots + c_{k}B^kA$$

Therefore $$B^{k+2}A = c_0 AB + c_1 B^2A + \ldots + c_{k}(c_0 A + c_1 BA + \ldots + c_{k}B^kA)$$

Continue this way, we can partition the matrix into one set of $k$ linearly independent columns and $n - k$ linearly dependent columns

Do I have this correctly? Is there a general theorem governing this result?

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. note that if $A$ is the zero vector then all the columns of $M$ are too, so $M$ has rank 0.

Comment: Use Gram Schmidt or QR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem arises from Linear Control Theory:observability. The matrix $M$ is called observability matrix. And there are some criteria on whether its rank is n.

Comment: There are schemes on searching for the linearly independent columns.But it's tedious:split the matrix $A$ into $n$ columns,then multiply $B^i$ and the first column,the number i ends when we find the first to be dependent with the previous vectors. Then multiply $B^i$ and the second column of $A$.The procedure ends when you find n linearly independent vectors.